# Setting dynamics IDs using Jade/Pug

Tags: angularjs, html, pug

I'm struggling to set dynamic Ids using Jade/Pug.

I got a table with a checkbox column, and I'm trying to set an dynamic/random `id` in those checkboxes. I'm using `#item$index`, but it doesn't work.

That's my code:

```
tbody(table-select='ms.tableSelectConfig', ng-model='ms.selected')
    tr(ng-repeat='item in ms.items', table-select-item='item')
        td
            table-select-checkbox#item$index
        td {{item.code}}
        td {{item.name}}
        td {{item.component|const:'components'}}
    tr(ng-if='ms.items.length<1')
        td(colspan='4') Nothing found.
```

Comment: You are mixing angular and pug templating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing it with Angular template syntax. It could be written in Pug as:

```
table-select-checkbox(id= "item"+index)
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to concatenate angular $index with "item", so I have the checkbox id related to the checkbox itself.

Comment: I just found out my mistake. It is working this way:  
table-select-checkbox(id="{{item.code}}")/